# Ansible-vault file for ssh Authentication

Tags: linux, ansible

I'm trying to make a file for storing ssh username and password using ansible vault so it would be encrypted. Is it possible to use that encrypted file in the playbook or inventory so the file will be using for ssh Authentication and it will automaticaly decrypted when executing the playbook for ssh?

I'm trying to make the file in .pass and add my ssh username and password then encrypted it using ansible vault but I have no idea how to use that file for ssh Authentication or is it not possible?